# Calling Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread in loop or before loop?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to figure out what would be best for performance? I have to add about 30 pins at a time. This code is in a method called from a `Task.Run();`

```
if (Pins != null)
    foreach (Pin pin in Pins)
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => Map.Pins.Add(pin));
```

Or

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => 
{
    if (Pins != null)
        foreach (Pin pin in Pins)
            Map.Pins.Add(pin));
});
```

Comment: second way is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you would have guessed, the second example is better. Additionally, this is mobile land, so what ever performance gains you can get, take them.

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => 
{
    if (Pins != null)
        foreach (Pin pin in Pins)
            Map.Pins.Add(pin));
});
```

You aren't mashing to the UI thread every iteration.

Also i would consider another step, if `Map.Pins` an `ObservableCollection` and `Pins` is an `IEnumerbale` and/or `List` add them all at once, This saves calling/raising the notification every time.

```
Map.Pins = Pins;
// or
Map.Pins = new ObservableCollection(Pins);
// raise notification depending on your plumbing
```

If you need to add to the existing `ObservableCollection`, unfortunatly it dosnt support `AddRange()`, so consider creating a whole new instance, then replacing it. Once again this depends on your hows and whys.

```
var temp = new ObservableCollection(Map.Pins);

foreach (Pin pin in Pins)
   temp.Add(pin);

Map.Pins = Temp;
```

**Update** from SushiHangover

> Pins is a read-only property

So the bulk update isn't applicable (as shown above)

Comment: @SushiHangover thanks for the heads up. I haven't use them before